# Assign associated objects by association name (as string) in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :subitems
end

Class SubItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :item
end
```

I have an instance of Item and an array of subitems, but I only have the name of the association (as string). How to assign subitems to item?

```
item = Item.new
subitems = [] << SubItem.new << SubItem.new << SubItem.new

item.("subitems".do_some_magic) = subitems
item.save
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
item.send("subitems") = subitems
item.save!
```

Comment: Based on your answer, I found a solution which works: item.send "subitems=".to_sym, subitems Thx